# Neo4j native Java: Creating a new database in memory rather than hard disk

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

As a part of graph decomposition, I split a graph to multiple ones. 
In order to use them in the next procedures, I want to store splitted graphs in a data structure.
How can I store these multiple graphs by a data structure in a memory rather than using disk path for that?
If I use newEmbeddedDatabase for that, I should provide a path which is not my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two main options to do this.

**Option 1**

You can use an `ImpermanentGraphDatabase` as seen [in this link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html) where unit testing with neo4j is discussed.   Note that this actually does still write temporary files, you just don't need to know/care where they are stored.

**Option 2**

The second option is to use linux to set up something like [ramfs](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/).  The idea here is that you're actually creating something which *looks* like a disk, but it's actually all in memory and so transient/not saved to a hard disk.  This option lets you treat your in-memory graph databases just like any other (just another directory on disk).

Neo4j doesn't have an option to do things purely in memory with no persistence to disk, so either of these options lets you do what you want, without having to really think about the disk persistence bits.